# Azure DevOps API for create new projects and pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-3.1

In my organization there are a lot of researchers and each of them has few projects. For each project, I have to create a repository in Azure DevOps and a pipeline. I'm using **.NET Core 3.1** but I can update to **.NET5**.

Apart from the name, the pipeline is the same for each project. What I want to create is a simple internal website where each researcher can add its project number and automatically the website call Azure DevOps via API to create a new repository and a new pipeline.

I tried to run the project from the [Microsoft repository](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples) on GitHub but the examples don't work. What I want to achieve is a very simple piece of code that can create a new repository with an associate pipeline.

I saw the branch *OAuthWebSampleAspNetCore.csproj* in the same [Microsoft repository](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/users/wismythe/oauth-web-sample-aspnet-core). There is a `OAuthController` that seems correct based on the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) but it doesn't work. The following code creates the request to Azure DevOps.

```
private String BuildAuthorizationUrl(String state)
{
    UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(this.Settings.AuthorizationUrl);
    var queryParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query ?? String.Empty);

    queryParams["client_id"] = this.Settings.ClientApp.Id.ToString();
    queryParams["response_type"] = "Assertion";
    queryParams["state"] = state;
    queryParams["scope"] = this.Settings.ClientApp.Scope;
    queryParams["redirect_uri"] = this.Settings.ClientApp.CallbackUrl;

    uriBuilder.Query = queryParams.ToString();

    return uriBuilder.ToString();
}
```

This is the URL the application calls

> https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com:443/oauth2/authorize?client_id=myClientId&response_type=Assertion&state=6ca228c6-f73f-48be-9a0a-38c8f2483837&scope=myListOfScopes&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a43742%2foauth%2fcallback

and this is the result from Azure DevOps.

[image]

The next part is the **callback**. Based on the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#http-request-body), I have to call the token URL `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token` as POST. The following code is how I do the request.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Callback(String code, Guid state)
{
    TokenViewModel tokenViewModel = new TokenViewModel() { OAuthSettings = this.Settings };

    string error;
    if (ValidateCallbackValues(code, state.ToString(), out error))
    {
        // Exchange the auth code for an access token and refresh token
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, this.Settings.TokenUrl);
        requestMessage.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        Dictionary<String, String> form = new Dictionary<String, String>()
                {
                    { "client_assertion_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer" },
                    { "client_assertion", GetClientAppSecret() },
                    { "grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" },
                    { "assertion", code },
                    { "redirect_uri", this.Settings.ClientApp.CallbackUrl }
                };
        requestMessage.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(form);

        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await s_httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

        if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            String body = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Token token = s_authorizationRequests[state];
            JsonConvert.PopulateObject(body, token);

            tokenViewModel.Token = token;
        }
        else
        {
            error = responseMessage.ReasonPhrase;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        tokenViewModel.Error = error;
    }

    return View("TokenView", tokenViewModel);
}
```

Although, I think, I have a valid token and `IsSuccessStatusCode` is always `false` because a `BadRequest`.

Are there any updated samples I can use? Did someone face the same issues?

Answer (score 0):

> https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com:443/oauth2/authorize?client_id=myClientId&response_type=Assertion&state=6ca228c6-f73f-48be-9a0a-38c8f2483837&scope=myListOfScopes&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a43742%2foauth%2fcallback

I found you used your `localhost` as your Callback URL.

You cannot use your localhost as the callback url, for your localhost is unavailable to azure devops services.

You have to use a callback url that can be accessed from the public network. Or you will get above `400-bad request` error.

Comment: Thanks but how can I test my code? How can I develop a solution on my machine?

Comment: @Enrico You can consider using  [ngrok.com](https://ngrok.com/) . Or creating a empty azure web app as the callback url to get the code.

Comment: @Enrico Hi How did it with this case? Could you accept above answer, if you think it qualifies as the answer